# In ViewPager, Fragment (n+1) depends on user input in Fragment (n). How to create Fragment (n+1)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

The ViewPager object is implemented such that the next screen is already created in memory before the user swipes to it. ViewPager has a method setOffscreenPageLimit(n) in which you can set the number of ViewPager fragments that are created in advance, but n=0 is not allowed. The reason behind that is to garantee a 'smooth user experience'. In my case however then content of page n+1 is determined by what the user has done on page n. For instance if the user has clicked on a checkbox on page n, it can happen that some widget should not be shown on page n+1. My question is: how can I ensure that page n+1 is recreated? If that goes at the cost of a 'smooth user experience' so be it. I am able to intercept the swipe event in:

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
```

In that method I can call a refresh() method of the current fragment. The problem is: what do I do in that refresh() method or is this the wrong approach? The user interface I want to recreate is in the onCreate method, a callback method. Or can't this work and do I need to replace the Fragment (n+1) in memory with a new one and if so, how do I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "For instance if the user has clicked on a checkbox on page n, it can happen that some widget should not be shown on page n+1" -- trying to forcibly recreate a page in a `ViewPager` to hide a widget is akin to trying to avoid vacuuming by burning down your house. If you want to hide a widget based upon the checkbox, then **hide the widget**. Either push the checkbox event to the affected fragment, or pull the checkbox state when the fragment becomes visible.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea! It happens to be the case that the page n+1 that is created in memory, has a bunch of widgets (either radiogroup of group of checkboxes) of which several need to be hidden, but not newly created. Recreating the page is indeed not necessary. Thanks!

Comment: I implemented it and it does indeed work. The problem now is that there are holes in the column of radiobuttons. I hope I can find a way to 'contract' the column to eliminate the holes caused by the hidden widgets. Thanks again.

Comment: Make sure you use `View.GONE`, not `View.INVISIBLE`.

Comment: Now this is a fine way to get out of bed in the morning, one headache less. Works perfectly, thanks again! (If your formulate it into a formal answer I can give you the kudos, if you care about these things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to replace the fragment associated with a page in a `ViewPager` is going to be the responsibility of your fragment-based `PagerAdapter`. I am not aware of an easy way to accomplish that with `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. [My `ArrayPagerAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager) can handle it better, though I don't offer a direct `replace()` operation.

In your case, the better solution is to adjust the fragment that you have, rather than to replace the fragment outright. In theory, this should be possible for just about any degree of change. In practice, there is probably a level of complexity after which trying to replace the fragment would be simpler than trying to have a mashup of all possible fragments.

Note that nested fragments might be another option, where the N+1th page was a placeholder and ran a `FragmentTransaction` to populate itself when shown. Nested fragments are tricky and quirky.

With regards to the "holes", `View.INVISIBLE` indicates that you want the widget to continue taking up space (e.g., so stuff after it in a `LinearLayout` does not move), but do not draw the pixels. `View.GONE` means that the `View` is totally ignored for layout purposes, though it is still in the hierarchy and so can be easily toggled back to `View.VISIBLE` if needed. Another possibility would be to remove the `View` entirely from the parent container, though this should have no visible change when compared with `View.GONE`.